# Excel VBA: Listbox Error when assigning Linked Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have some cells with Data Validation. Because the dropdown list is small and hard to read, I have a button which opens a list box and populates it with the cell's Data Validation list.

```
Dim btnAddToList As OLEObject
Public lboTemp As OLEObject

Set btnAddToList = ws.OLEObjects("btnAddToList")
Set lboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempListBoxS")
Set Field = Selection  ' This is always cell $D$1, $D$2, or $D$3

       btnAddToList.Visible = False

      'Create a named range "temp" 
       ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="temp", RefersTo:=Field.Validation.Formula1

        ' open list box
        ' position list box
        ' load it with "temp"
 With lboTemp
     'show the listbox with the list
     .Visible = True
     .Left = Field.Left
     .Top = Field.Top + 50
     .ListFillRange = "temp"     
     .Object.MultiSelect = 0  ' Single select
      On Error GoTo errHandler
      prev = .LinkedCell
      If prev <> "" Then prev = prev & ": " & Range(.LinkedCell).Value  ' for debugging
      .LinkedCell = Field.Address  'SOMETIMES THIS GIVES Err 440: could not set property value, invalid property value
      .Width = Field.Width + 5
      .Height = WorksheetFunction.Min(270, .Object.ListCount * 20) 'field.Height + 5
 End With
```

As noted in the comment above, I sometimes, but not always, I get an error when the LinkedCell is supposed to be populated by with the Field.Address.

This code is used by six different cells (D1:D3 on two different worksheets), but the error only appears to occur when one of the D1 cells is the one selected. Those cells have one other thing in common: their data validation lists, respectively, are:
  ='Category Table'!$F$2:$F$31   and 
  ='Category Table'!$F$32:$F$41

The other four cells -- which don't get the error -- use a complicated dynamic range that references a different table on the "Category Table" sheet. (I don't really think this has anything to do with my problem, but I don't see anything else those cells have in common)

If no one can give me an answer, I'd appreciate some advice on how to track down an intermittent problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already done any debugging? You can debug by inserting a break (F9) on one of the first functional lines. Now when the script triggers you will enter debug mode and can run the remainder line by line while wathcing locals (use local watch window: View > Locals). This way you can probably pinpoint the exact line that is causing the problem.

Comment: @K_B The trouble is the line `.LinkedCell = Field.Address`. I'm trying the Locals window, but there are a lot of properties and as of now, nothing stands out. I did just realize something, though: the error doesn't actually seem have an effect!  The LinkedCell is assigned like I tell it to, whether or not that line raises an error. I'll probably just put an `On Error Resume Next` before it. But I'd still like to know why this is happening -- in case it has further-reaching consequences. Any ideas?

Comment: you can also use a watch window and select only a limited number of local variables to watch. Also use the immediate window to execute some extra code, such as `Debug.Print`.

Comment: I am not usre either why this happens, however maybe Field is sometimes not a single cell? What happens when you do `.LinkedCell = Field.Cells(1,1).Address`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the return of `Field.Address`. The `.Adress` property returns, by default, with the absolute value of row and column. You can try `Field.Address(RowAabsolute:=false, ColumnAbsolute:=false)` . Hope this help.
and sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to stop this issue by ensuring that the linked cell was empty before creating the reference.